# How to prohibit making a copy of a public field or property in C#

Tags: c#, properties, field, wrapper

Is it possible to prohibit making a reference copy of a public field or property like in the following example?

```c#
Foo foo = new Foo();

foo.bar.DoSomething(); // That's fine
Bar myRefToBar = foo.bar; // Don't allow this!
```

When "bar" gets exchanged inside "foo", "myRefToBar" will still point to the original "bar".

What I'm trying to achive is that either:

- "myRefToBar" automatically Points to the new "bar" object, or
- prohibit making a copy of "bar" in the first place.

The obvious solution would be to make "bar" private and write a wrapper function like:

```c#
class Foo
{
  private Bar bar;

  public void DoSomethingWithBar()
  {
    bar.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

But lets say "Bar" has hundreds of functions and I want all of them available, do I have to write hundreds of wrappers, or is there a simpler way of achiving this?

Comment: The right way to go about this would be to make sure you're not doing silly things in your code which uses `foo.bar`.  Trying to work around language semantics in this way is not going to lead to a good design.  Also, the answer is "no", at least, not if you want to have a public property of type `Bar`.  See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx

Comment: I think the "obvious solution" is the best.  Happy wrapping.

Comment: `"Bar" has hundreds of functions and I want all of them available` sounds like the problem - separation of concerns. Break it up into bite sized interfaces grouping logical functionality. You might find that `Foo` doesn't need all of them, and won't need to expose all, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you're doing by writing `foo.Bar` is exposing a reference to that object.  What they do with the object at that point is up to them.  They can store it for later use (as `var bar = foo.Bar`) or operate on it directly (as `foo.Bar.DoSomething()`).  The only way to keep them from doing this would be to, as you said, not expose it at all.

Answer (score 0):

> When "bar" gets exchanged inside "foo", "myRefToBar" will still point
>   to the original "bar".

Yes, that's true. Are you likely to swap bar a lot? Is there some kind of indication that bar is going to become invalid? If I'm using a class that exposes references I don't necessarily expect them to change unless I call a method such as `ReplaceBar(newBar)`

> What I'm trying to achive is that either:
>   • "myRefToBar" automatically Points to the new "bar" object, or
>   • prohibit making a copy of "bar" in the first place.

I'm not sure why you have this goal, make it obvious that bar can change, when it has changed and preferably when it will change.

> The obvious solution would be to make "bar" private and write a
>   wrapper function

Actually to me the most obvious solution is to name bar `CurrentBar` or use a method `GetTemporaryBar()` which indicates it changes. 
The second step I'd make is if Bar can be invalid I'd make it `IDisposable` and dispose the old Bar when I swapped it out. Any method called on an invalid `Bar` should now raise an `ObjectDisposedException`; I would still be surprised if my reference to bar became invalid halfway through a local method without me calling something that made it clearly my fault.

Comment: I like the `IDisposable` approach, as in my case `Bar` is a communication link that may get invalid and is automatically replaced. So someone using an old reference would get an `ObjectDisposedException` as you suggested.